# How to setup conditionals for BPMN2 Exclusive Gateway

Tags: java, spring, bpmn, camunda

I'm using Camunda BPMN2 for the first time in my spring project and trying to get my head around a couple of things ...

In my applicationContext, I have the following block to setup Camunda:

```
    <!-- Setup BPMN Process Engine -->
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="processEngineName" value="engine" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:*.bpmn" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />
    <context:annotation-config />
```

I've setup two services:

```
@Component(value="service1")
public class Service1 implements JavaDelegate {
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {     
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        System.out.println("SERVICE1");     
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");      
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component(value="service2")
public class Service2 implements JavaDelegate {
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        System.out.println("SERVICE2");     
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }
}
```

In scenario 1 I have a parallel gateway that calls both Service1 and Service2 (I've built these diagrams using BPMN2 editor in eclipse):

[image: scenario 1]

[image: scenario 1 - service 1]

[image: scenario 1 - service 2]

Running this line of code:

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("ConnectorSwitch");
```

Prints out

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
SERVICE1
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
SERVICE2
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

as expected.

Now I'm trying to put in an Exclusive Gateway:

[image]

Running it gives me the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Error while closing command context                                                                                                                                                                                                 
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Exclusive Gateway 'ExclusiveGateway_3' has outgoing sequence flow 'SequenceFlow_39' without condition which is not the default flow. | ..../ConnectorSwitch.bpmn | line 0 | column 0                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Exclusive Gateway 'ExclusiveGateway_3' has outgoing sequence flow 'SequenceFlow_40' without condition which is not the default flow. | ..../ConnectorSwitch.bpmn | line 0 | column 0                 

        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:183)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:177)     
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.deploy(BpmnDeployer.java:106)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:50)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:42)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:81)                                        
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:50)                                        
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)            
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) 
    ......
```

The exception is pretty clear, I'm missing a condition on the Exclusive Gateway.
So my question is, how do I assign a condition to the exclusive gateway, how do I call a method in a certain class and evaluate the true / false and if I want to call something else that is not a JavaDelegate for service1 / service2 (in other words, MyClass.doSomethingWithParams(someparam)), how would I go about that?

Answers in XML is fine as well, would prefer to learn how to use BPMN2 in XML instead of relying on the BPMN2 visuals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *Camunda Modeler*, click on one of the sequence flows coming out of your exclusive gateway. Then select the `Properties` pane and the `General` subpane. You will see an attribute `Condition`. This attribute can be populated with a JUEL expression just like the one that you used for the delegates. You can use your Spring beans there and e.g. call a method on them. So if `myClass` is a Spring bean name, just write `${myClass.doSomethingWithParams(someparam)}`. Or you can access process variables that are already attached to your process instance. `someparam` could be such a variable e.g. -> Just make sure that all the outgoing sequence flows have such a condition attached. Then your process will run again. Maybe start first with a simple condition like `${true}` and `${false}`. If this works, move on and do something more complex. And have fun! :-)

Comment: Wow, the one place I didn't think it would be, thanks Martin :-)

Comment: You are very welcome in the (almost always) helpful community of camunda users. :-)