# Gateways in Activiti workflow

Tags: java, eclipse, activiti

I am using Activiti diagram in eclipse and am confused as to how to use the gateway tool? How do I configure the gateway tool in Activiti workflow? Is there a way I can link it to any java class?

Thanks

Comment: I do not have experience with Activiti, but I do have it with Camunda. So, IMHO I would say that it is better to use their Google Groups for this kind of questions.

Comment: thanks @facundofarias but I am looking for something in Activiti

Comment: I once wrote an answer about how to configure gateways in camunda. It should be the same like in activiti: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039720/how-to-setup-conditionals-for-bpmn2-exclusive-gateway/27040671#27040671

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I figured out the issue. Under properties, there is a Listeners option. In that option, we can change it to expression or java class depending upon the need. The java class or method would include the logic required for the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use listeners but if you want to make decision gateway you can simply click on flow and asign to them logical condition in properties:

http://postimg.org/image/weg8qil7j/